# Reference to support using binomial GLM for proportion response

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, references, binomial-distribution

I have a GLM where I'm predicting a proportion response (# correct items / total # of quiz items). The common recommendation in this case is to assume a binomial distribution and use a logit link. For example: [What are the issues with using percentage outcome in linear regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103731/what-are-the-issues-with-using-percentage-outcome-in-linear-regression) and [Regression for an outcome (ratio or fraction) between 0 and 1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29038/regression-for-an-outcome-ratio-or-fraction-between-0-and-1)

Some others in my department (varying levels of statistical knowledge) disagree, or agree but suggest the use of Poisson or a linear model for simplicity.

In addressing their concerns, and also anticipating reviewer responses to the analysis, I'm wondering if there are any references (e.g. journal articles) that I could cite that suggest/recommend binomial GLM for this type of outcome variable?

Comment: Any book on GLMs?  McCullagh and Nelder?  Hardin and Hilbe?

Comment: http://aem.asm.org/content/67/5/2129.full

Comment: See also:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/216122/what-is-the-difference-between-logistic-regression-and-fractional-response-regre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recommended in comments:

McCullagh, P., & Nelder, J. A. (1989). Generalized linear models (Monographs on Statistics and Applied Probability 37). CRC press.

Hardin, J. W. & Hilbe, J. M. (2007). Generalized linear models and extensions. Stata press.

Zhao, L., Chen, Y., & Schaffner, D. W. (2001). Comparison of logistic regression and linear regression in modeling percentage data. Applied and Environmental Microbiology, 67(5), 2129-2135.

Comment: h/t @TheLaconic

Comment: h/t @kjetilbhalvorsen