# How would you transform a percentage dependent variable to fit a logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model

I have a outcome variable that is a percentage (proportion).  According to this, I should probably use a logistic regression: [What are the issues with using percentage outcome in linear regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103731/what-are-the-issues-with-using-percentage-outcome-in-linear-regression)

**My goal is interpretation and my goal is to interpret actually only a single variable**.  So for example, Y = X1 + X2 + X3 + X4, I only care about the coefficient of X2.

Now, because my Y is actually a percentage and NOT a binary value, how would someone use a logistic regression to solve this problem?  It doesn't make sense to transform my Y to 0s and 1s with a threshold of 0.5, partly because the range of Y is between 0 and 0.3 and Y is not a binary variable.  It is literally a proportion (think how full a glass of water is) and so something binary just doesn't make sense.

Is there a way to transform Y to fit a logistic regression?  How would one model such a proportion?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see a reason why you couldn't just use a normal logistic or probit regression (possibly with robust standard errors) without any transformations. If you don't have 0s or 1s, you could also entertain beta regression.