# How to model a sigmoid function?

Tags: regression, sigmoid-curve

I have a variable where Y ~ sigmoid(X).  Y ranges between 0 and 1.  Y, however, is not a probability, so I don't know if I can just get a logistic regression.  What I do want is, for a change in X, how much does Y change.  How would I model this?  Obviously, different values of X leads to different changes in Y, depending on where you are on the sigmoid curve.

Thanks!

Comment: How would one do it? Most logistic models take 0,1 as the input for Y.  It doesn't make sense for me to convert my Y to 0 and 1.

Comment: Why not use beta regression? (See my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/29042/7290).)

Comment: I also found one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33033176/using-r-to-fit-a-sigmoidal-curve

Comment: Is the outcome continuous or discrete?

Comment: I suspect that the equations here might contain what you want: https://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/latest/curve-fitting/reg_classic_dr.htm