# Method to predict outcome as percentage of two categories?

Tags: regression, categorical-data, model, percentage

In real world example I have elemental composition data for groundwater, which is known to be coming from two sources. I have control data where all predictors are from source A and data where all predictors are from source B. I would like to be able to take an unknown water sample and predict what percentage is source A vs. B based on the elemental composition of that sample.

The problem is not obvious to me because it is not a categorical outcome, but rather the relative contribution of two potential categories - if that makes sense.

I've looked for similar questions but couldn't find one - be gentle! Thanks

Comment: You can make artificial training set, by taking an example from A and an example from B and making their linear combination.

Comment: You can use a binary logit model. [See this related post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/26779/12833).

Comment: Thanks Tim, i'll take a look at that option and see if it will be appropriate. Definitely couldn't find that before i posted!

Comment: This does not appear to be about a fraction of two counts but a continuous proportion of 2 positive real numbers.

Comment: Do you then anticipate that the method that Tim referenced would work?